# Why are these two strings == but not ===

Tags: javascript

I know I'm going to feel dumb at the end of this, but I've been struggling with this...

```
if (user._id == req.params.id) {
    console.log("match");           
} else {
    console.log("'" + user._id + "' does not match '" + req.params.id + "'");
}
```

This works, comparing two strings that are the same and finding a match.  But my jshint tells me to use this operator `===` which I understand ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)) to mean that types are also checked.

Substituting the `===` my test fails, generating console output like;

> '56e0a2085b89105924963dc3' does not match '56e0a2085b89105924963dc3'

I think the ticks `'` prove that there's no whitespace on either end.  That article indicates that either the types don't match or that one of the strings was created with a `new String` constructor, but I don't control the code that generates these.  What should I do?

1. transform them to something else to compare?  ...yuck, and to what?
2. suppress or ignore the jshint? ...that's how a lazy developer gets in trouble later
3. debug more?  ... but how?  I don't even know how to log the type of an object (in JS, that seems to be a whole other long trip through language weirdness).

Comment: Try doing a `typeof` on both, I'm guessing one of them is an object or buffer, maybe an ObjectID or similar, as Mongo generally uses `_id` for ObjectID's

Comment: if you realy need `===` you can do so: `if (String(user._id) === String(req.params.id)) {`

Comment: Yes.  typeof is a valuable hint, the two types are "objecttype" and "string".  @DmitriyLoskutov, does String(x) coerce objecttype into a string?

Comment: MongoDB's ObjectID's has their own `toString()` method, so you should be doing `if (user._id.toString() === req.params.id) {...`

Comment: But if `user._id` is `null` or `undefined`, you may get 'Reference Error'. But if it is MongoDB, I guess `.toString()` is enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using mongodb to get the objectId (I'm assuming from the syntax). You should check whether user._id is actually a string instead of an "ObjectId" object. You can pause execution or just use the typeof operator to see if user._id is actually a string.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right.  Different types.  I didn't realize that ObjectId was a thing.  What's the right way to get the string version of an object id?

Comment: Ah.. Found it!  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/  Thanks very much!  SO says I must wait 4 mins to accept.